# how to post with an anchor

Tags: html, submit, anchor

I would like to use an anchor instead of a button

The Button works as either a button or Submit, but the Anchor does not.

```
<form id="contact" action="includes/login.php" method="post" name="login_form">     
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);"/> 



<a href="includes/login.php" onclcik="return formhash(this.form, this.form.password);"><strong>Login</strong></a>
```

I'm sure its to do with passed/posted parameters but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('contact').submit();">click here</a>
```

This will post all the content of the form.

Comment: should post, but no function executed.

Comment: which function you want to execute

Comment: the input button has an onclick of formhash() which needs to be executed and passed.

Comment: can you upload your script

Comment: function formhash(form, password) {
    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();